# Scanner Java issue

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that parses a text file that I've got. If it starts with a "#", I skip to the next line. If I scan a low digit, I set the width to that number. If I encounter a word, I set the color to that word. If I encounter a larger number, I set x to the first number and y to the number right after it. Using all this information, it plots lines.

Here is my problem. If I do scan.next() in the condition, it moves onto the next word/number in the text file even if it didn't fit the condition, and I know that's how it's supposed to work. Same goes for scan.nextInt(). I don't know how I can check the next string/int in a text document without advancing in the text.

If you understand my issue, could you try and help me out? Thank you.

```
package lab7;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.Point;
import plotter.PolylinePlotter;

public class CheckpointTwo  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
    File file = new File("C:/Users/Nick/workspace/project7/test.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    PolylinePlotter plotter = new PolylinePlotter();
    while (scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
      String line = scanner.nextLine();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);
        String color = "";
        int width=0;

        while(scan.hasNext())
        {
            int x=0;
            int y=0;
            if(scan.next().equals("#"))
            {
                scan.nextLine();
                continue;
            }
            else if(scan.hasNextInt()==true && scan.nextInt()<10)
            {
                width=scan.nextInt();
                color=scan.next();
            }
            else if(scan.hasNextInt()==false && scan.hasNext()==true)
            {
                color=scan.next();
            }
            else if(scan.hasNextInt()==true && scan.nextInt()>10)
            {
                x=scan.nextInt();
                y=scan.nextInt();
            }
                 plotter.startLine(color, new Point(x,y));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the methods of the `Scanner` object? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html look for things starting with `hasNext...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `scan.nextInt()`, `scan.next()`, etc inside of your if-statement. This will still advance a line even though it is inside an if-statement because the method still has to be called in order to get the returned value. What you should do is get the next line and store it in a variable before your if-statement, then you can compare against the variable and not the method. For example:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);
    String color = "";
    int width=0;

    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
        int x=0;
        int y=0;

        boolean isInt = scan.hasNextInt();
        String next = scan.next();

        if(next.equals("#"))
        {
            scan.nextLine();
            continue;
        }
        else if(isInt && Integer.parseInt(next) < 10)
        {
            width=scan.nextInt();
            color=scan.next();
        }
        else if(!isInt)
        {
            color=next;
        }
        else if(isInt && Integer.parseInt(next) > 10)
        {
            x=scan.nextInt();
            y=scan.nextInt();
        }
        plotter.startLine(color, new Point(x,y));
    }
}
```

First I defined two variables:

```
boolean isInt = scan.hasNextInt();
String next = scan.next();
```

The first variable, `isInt`, stores whether or not the second variable, `next`, is an `int`. `next` stores `scan.next()`, clearly. Now we can use these two variables inside of our if-statement and we don't have to worry about accidentally calling `scan.next()` and advancing the `Scanner`. In the statements where you want to check if `next` is `> 10` or `< 10`, use `Integer.parseInt(String s)` to turn the `String` variable `next` into an `int`.

Let me know if this is confusing to you or if it doesn't work as expected and I can help. I hope this works out for you!

Comment: It's 2:30 in the morning so I won't fix it right now but I was thinking the same thing. I thought that maybe I could make the integers a string and grab them somehow. I just learned about parsing but I'm not too great at it so I wasn't sure how to do it. I'll update you if I can't fix my program tomorrow. Thank you for your great answer, it seems like it will work.

Comment: @NewbieNick No problem! Let me know how it works for you. I'll make sure you get it working!

Comment: Update: It's beginning to work. I had to add a variable or two and change some things but your idea is working. I finally got the program to grab information from the file and graph some of it, but not all of it quite yet.

Comment: @NewbieNick Awesome! If you have any specific problems let me know

Comment: Ok. I finally got the whole program to work. Thank you so much, you've taught me how to parse correctly.

Comment: @NewbieNick That is what I was hoping for! So many people on StackOverflow only give fish, I try to teach how to fish. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your test condition must be

```
if(s.equals("#"))
```

Coz you already read a line and stored it in the variable `String s`

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that in each iteration of the while loop, only one nextXXX method gets called.
2. Write System.out.println and print stuff.
3. Step through your code in your IDE (Eclipse)
4. If you're not using an IDE, start using one.

Comment: Yes, I just learned how to step through code last week and I've been using that. I was able to fix a few previous errors based off of that. I would print things out but I specifically need to grab values and store them in a variable so I can input them into a method that will plot the points. This would be much easier if I could simply print it out *sigh* But this is important for me to learn anyway so I'm happy that I have to go through these challenges.

Comment: Great - all the best!